# Are there criteria for using Shared Buffer in AUTOSAR?

Tags: autosar

I wonder if there is a specification not to use a shared buffer in the autosar standard.

I know that each message has its own buffer.

Thank you.

Comment: Which "shared buffers" do you mean? Do you mean in Com, or do you mean the HRH/HTH on Can/CanIf level?

Comment: It is based on tx message .I think that using multiple messages as one buffer, unlike the case of using one buffer for each message.